# parameters getting method is this correct or wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to get data with click to link.
There are my links;

```
<a class="note" id="' . $data["p_id"] . '" value="1" href="javascript:void(0)">+1</a>
<a class="note" id="' . $data["p_id"] . '" value="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">-1</a>
```

I'm using this code with using $.ajax. I have to get value and "$data["p_id"]" but my usage is true or false?

And my JQuery code:

```
 $("a[class=note]").click(function( evt ){
                    var note = $(this).attr("value");
                    var preid = $(this).attr("id");
                    alert(note);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'style/ajax.php',
                        data: 'do=note&value=' + note + '&preid=' + preid
                    });
                });
```

Comment: I must admit that your question is unclear to me. What do you mean with "true" or "false? Do you mean some boolean value or are you just asking whether your usage of $.ajax() is right or wrong? Your usage is ok, but you'll need to implement the success callback to be able to handle the PHP script output

Comment: for example normally value parameters is for form element. but I'm using for "a".. is this usage is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points

- all element ids should be unique
- there's no "value" attribute for "a" tags
- you should return `false` from `click` handlers to prevent the default action
- `ajax` is a low-level method, consider [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
- when using ajax it's better to provide alternate navigation for non-javascript browsers, that is, to have a functioning "href" attribute for links. In your case, since the links are not meant to be followed by search engines, it's more "semantic" to use `input`s or `button`s instead.

Example:

```
<button class="note" name="plus" value="$data["p_id"]">+1</button>
<button class="note" name="minus" value="$data["p_id"]">-1</button>

$("button.note").click(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var note = name == "plus" ? 1 : -1;
    var id = $(this).attr("value");
    $.get("style/ajax.php?do=note&value=" + note + "&preid=" + id);
    return false;
})
```

Comment: +1. Add to the "points list" `$("a[class=note]")` => `$("a.note")`